# Weird behaviour when trying to get the subsections of a Date object in Google App Script Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to use the Date object in Google Apps Script, however I narrowed down some weird behaviour when trying to get the separate elements of a Date out of said object (year, month, day).
Here's my code:

```
var beginningTimeValue = new Date('2020-01-01 08:00:00');
  var endingTimeValue = new Date('2020-01-01 13:00:00');
  var unique = [["value","value","value","value","12/01/2021 00:03:35","value"],["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 00:03:35","value"], ["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 08:03:35","value"], ["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 13:03:35","value"]]
  
  if(!beginningTimeValue == ""){
    unique = unique.filter(function(row)
                              {
                                var rYear = row[4].substring(6, 10);
                                var rMonth = row[4].substring(3, 5);
                                var rDay = row[4].substring(0, 2);
                                var rHour = row[4].substring(11, 12);
                                var rMinute = row[4].substring(13, 14);
                                var rSecond = row[4].substring(15, 16);
                                var bTime = new Date(rYear, rMonth-1, rDay);
                                console.log("DATE = " + rYear + "/" + rMonth + "/" + rDay);
                                console.log("DATE = " + bTime.getYear() + "/" + bTime.getMonth() + "/" + bTime.getDate());

                                beginningTimeValue.setYear(bTime.getYear());
                                beginningTimeValue.setMonth(bTime.getMonth());
                                beginningTimeValue.setDate(bTime.getDate());
                                return bTime.getTime() >= beginningTimeValue.getTime();
                              }
                             );
  }
```

The results of the console from the code written above are:

```
> "DATE = 2021/01/12"
> "DATE = 17/6/17"
> "DATE = 2020/01/01"
> "DATE = 6/6/6"
> "DATE = 2020/01/01"
> "DATE = 6/6/6"
> "DATE = 2020/01/01"
> "DATE = 6/6/6"
```

I've followed the constructor of the Date, so I have no idea why the console would print such weird results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problem in another question from 11 years ago. I needed to replace `.getYear()` with `.getFullYear().`

Comment: You can/should actually reference that OTHER question and close yours as a duplicate (which is quite OK to do)